# Threading Issue while using JNI with CORBA

Tags: java, multithreading, java-native-interface, corba, pthread-join

I have a Java application which is using JNI. Using Main thread of java I am creating a pthread eg. t1(using pthread_create) in native.

I also have a UI which is interacting with my java application with IDL & CORBA. From UI when I call my Close() in java, then it will try to do pthread_join() of thread t1 in native. But this pthread_join() failed, because it is trying to joined by different thread other than Main thread. 
I am suspecting that here CORBA thread is not switching to main thread. Please suggest me how to perform phread_join().

Comment: What does "trying to joined by different thread" mean?

Comment: Java Main thread create native thread t1, But any other thread (may be CORBA) is trying to join t1 thread.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that. The only requirement for pthread_join() is that t1 be joinable.